# How to trigger a validation to happen in knockout

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, knockout-validation

I'm developing an application which schedules a job. Now, I have radio buttons for *Monthly*, *Weekly*, *Daily* and for specific days. Now, if the user selects the last radio button, I show checkboxes for all days(Sunday, Monday...). I have put knockout validations for the radio buttons

```
 self.processSchedule.ScheduleType.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        resetSubcontrolsForScheduleType();
    });
```

Now, if the radio button selection is changed, the validation on the radio buttons is getting triggered correctly. What I need is if any of the checkboxes for the days are checked, I need that validation on the radio buttons to be triggered. Is there a way we can have a validation on radio buttons get triggered when the value of a checkbox is changed?

Comment: Here is how I'm validating the radio button.    self.processSchedule.ScheduleType.extend({
        validation: {
            validator: function (val, someOtherVal) {
                if (self.processSchedule.ScheduleType().toString() == "1") {
                    return isAnyOfTheSpecificDaysSelected();
                } else {
                    return true;
                }

            },
            message: 'Please select atleast one day.'
        }
    });

Comment: ScheduleType is a Radio button set and currently this is happening if the radio button's value gets changed. 
  I want this to happen on a checkbox getting checked/unchecked.